# How can i make outputLabel value change according to a condition?

Tags: jsf, icefaces-1.8

I have the following outputLabe code in jsf:

```
<ice:outputLabel value="#{litApp.TipusTramitImportAtorgat}" rendered="#{tipusTramitBB.detailEntity.id == 12}"/>
```

It appears only if tipusTramitBB.detailEntity.id == 12, if not it must have an other value, is there anyway to do it in this same outputLabel or i have to add an other outputLabel which appears if tipusTramitBB.detailEntity.id != 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in one label:

```xml
<ice:outputLabel value="#{tipusTramitBB.detailEntity.id == 12 ? litApp.TipusTramitImportAtorgat : litApp.otherValue}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though 2 labels with `rendered` attribute could have the same semantic, it is better to have the only element with same behavior for some reasons: clearer code and thus better maintenance, ajax rerendering, etc.

One solution is (as @Geinmachi mentioned) using of ternary operator:

```
<ice:outputLabel value="#{tipusTramitBB.detailEntity.id == 12 ? litApp.TipusTramitImportAtorgat : litApp.otherValue}"/>
```

Another solution (and I prefer this one) is to put your business logic direct in the managed bean (`litApp` in your case), something like:

```
public class LitApp {

    public Object getTipusTramitImportAtorgat() {
        if (tipusTramitBB.getDetailEntity.getId() == 12) {
            return "Value1";
        } else {
            return "Value2";
        }
    }
}
```

You have to get access to the `tipusTramitBB` bean from the `litApp`, but this is another question.

This is a general approach, but is often preferable, especially if you have a more complex business logic. Rendered attribute has another meaning, it designed for occasional hiding of element while rendering.